# Newton Method with a Parameter in the equation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I know the Raphson Newton method for the equation $f(x)=e^{-x}-x$, it is written with the following code

```
f[x_]:=Exp[-x]-x
Plot[Exp[-x]-x,{x,0,3}]
x1=0.5-(f[0.5]/f'[0.5])
```

However, I face difficulties when I try to create a code for the same equation with a parameter for example $f(x)=e^{-x}-ax$.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear[f, a];
f[a_][x_] = Exp[-x] - a*x;
x1 = 0.5 - (f[a][0.5]/f[a]'[0.5])
x1 = 0.5 - (f[a][.5]/Derivative[1][f[a]][.5])
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it's easiier to use `NestList`?

```
f[x_] := Exp[-x] - a x
NestList[# - f[#]/f'[#]  &, 0, 3]  // Simplify
%/.a->1. (*{0, 0.5, 0.566311, 0.567143}*)
```